# Preserving state between tab view pages

Tags: flutter, listview, dart, flutter-layout, tabview

#### issue

I have two `ListViews` rendering inside of a `TabBarView` using a `TabController`.

How do I preserve state (for lack of a better word) between each `ListView` so that: 1.) the Widgets don't rebuild and 2.) the `ListView` position is remembered between tabs.

#### relevant code

```
class AppState extends State<App> with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  TabController _tabController;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _tabController = new TabController(
      vsync: this,
      length: _allPages.length,
    );
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _tabController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  Widget _buildScaffold(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
      appBar: new AppBar(
        title: new Text('headlines'),
        bottom: new TabBar(
            controller: _tabController,
            isScrollable: true,
            tabs: _allPages
                .map((_Page page) => new Tab(text: page.country))
                .toList()),
      ),
      body: new TabBarView(
          controller: _tabController,
          children: _allPages.map((_Page page) {
            return new SafeArea(
              top: false,
              bottom: false,
              child: new Container(
                key: new ObjectKey(page.country),
                child: new Newsfeed(country: page.country),
              ),
            );
          }).toList()),
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new MaterialApp(
      title: 'news app',
      home: _buildScaffold(context),
    );
  }
}
```

#### illustrating gif

https://media.giphy.com/media/2ysWhzqHVqL1xcBlBE/giphy.gif

Answer (score 163, accepted):

In case you want to keep the state of your screen in your `TabBarView`, you can use the mixin class called `AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin` in your State class.

After that you have to override the `wantKeepAlive` method and return `true`. It will looks like something that :

```
class _SearchScreenState extends State<SearchScreen> with AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin<SearchScreen>{

...

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) { 
    // call this method
    super.build(context); 

    /// your widget here
  }

  @override
  bool get wantKeepAlive => true;

}
```

I wrote a post about that here:  https://medium.com/@diegoveloper/flutter-persistent-tab-bars-a26220d322bc

Comment: I have a video about this https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3v4ZofYsn5I  in spanish but you can enable english subtitles.

Answer (score 34):

Long story short, use a PageStorageKey() for your ListView or one of it's ancestors, the Container widget in your case:

```
child: Container(
    key: PageStorageKey(page.country),
    child: Newsfeed(country: page.country),
),
```

See details here:

- https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/PageStorageKey-class.html
- https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/PageStorage-class.html
- https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/ScrollView/controller.html

Comment: Will this keep only 1 attribute stored?

Comment: Please take a look below for a better solution from @diegoveloper

Answer (score 0):

Try containing your children views in a stack with an offset. It helped me save the state of my bottom bar navigation.