# Flutter - moving between tabs cause to lose the state

Tags: flutter, dart, web-applications

I am issue a weird situation. I have the following code that display the tabs and their contents:

```
Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Title'),
        actions: [
          IconButton(
            icon: Icon(Icons.add),
            onPressed: () => _onTabAdd(_tabController.index),
          ),
          IconButton(
            icon: Icon(Icons.delete),
            onPressed: () => _onTabRemoved(_tabController.index),
          ),
          IconButton(
            icon: Icon(Icons.edit),
            onPressed: () => _onTabEdit(context),
          ),
        ],
        bottom: PreferredSize(
          preferredSize: Size.fromHeight(40.0),
          child: Container(
            color: Colors.blue,
            child: TabBar(
              controller: _tabController,
              tabs: tabTitles
                  .map(
                    (title) => Tab(text: title),
                  )
                  .toList(),
              labelColor: Colors.yellow,
              unselectedLabelColor: Colors.white,
              indicatorSize: TabBarIndicatorSize.label,
              indicatorPadding: EdgeInsets.all(5.0),
              indicatorColor: Colors.red,
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
      body: TabBarView(
        controller: _tabController,
        children: tabContents.map((e) => e).toList(),
      ),
```

You can see that I have the option to add or delete Tabs using the buttons, and it seems to work fine using the following functions:

```
void _onTabRemoved(int index) {
    setState(() {
      tabTitles.removeAt(index);
      tabContents.removeAt(index);
      _tabController = TabController(length: tabTitles.length, vsync: this);
    });
  }

void _onTabAdd(int index) {
    setState(() {
      tabTitles.add("Tab ${tabTitles.length}");
      tabContents.add(GenesTable(this));
      _tabController = TabController(length: tabTitles.length, vsync: this);
    });
  }
```

The problem is that when I move between tabs I lose the state of `GenesTable` component (that store the table's content), meaning that when I move between tabs The table that been display is empty.

Comment: seems you need `AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can go through the answer given here
https://stackoverflow.com/a/51225319/13927133

In case you want to keep the state of your screen in your `TabBarView`, you can use the `mixin` class called `AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin` in your State class.

And after that override the `wantKeepAlive` method and return true.

@diegoveloper also posted a medium article for this
https://medium.com/@diegoveloper/flutter-persistent-tab-bars-a26220d322bc